# Selecting a default repository when pulling images from podman or docker

Tags: docker, podman

I created a script (so that I could automate whatever), but `docker` or `podman` asks me where to pull my images.

```
$ ./myscript
...
...
...
...
podman run --rm -it what/ever bash -i
? Please select an image:
  > registry.fedoraproject.org/what/ever:latest
    registry.access.redhat.com/what/ever:latest
    docker.io/what/ever:latest
    quay.io/what/ever:latest
```

Is there a way to make it always pull from `docker.io`?

Comment: If you put just "docker.io" in the `unqualified-search-registries` list does that not do it?